# Can SQL reads return stale data?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

Consider the following SQL transaction sequence:

```sql
// @TransactionOne
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE T (C INT, D INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 2);
COMMIT;

// @TransactionTwo
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 4);
COMMIT;

// @Query
SELECT COUNT(*) from T where T.C = 3;
```

The naive expectation is that @Query will return 1. However, when I read about ACID, it is not obvious to me that a database cannot reorder the sequence of operations to be: [@TransactionOne, @Query, @TransactionTwo] in which case it would return 0.

Is that allowed by the SQL standard? What guarantee to typical database engines provide for such cases?

I am also thinking of a high-throughput OLTP engine with some sort of read replica. Depending on the consistency model of the read replicas, the replicas may be slightly behind. That seems like a case where this scenario can occur with reasonable probability.

If this is indeed allowed, which of the ACID properties are being traded off here?

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no order of execution. It is a declarative language. The optimizer is free to choose any order it feels appropriate to produce the best execution time. Given a SQL query, it is impossible for anybody to know the execution order. If you add detailed information about the schema involved (exact tables and indexes definition) and the estimated cardinalities (size of data and selectivity of keys) then one can take a guess at the probable execution order.

You can, however, utilize things like Server Utility Statements in SQL Server, such as the 'Go' statement. 'Go' statements break queries into batches sent separately to be processed. The following code run in SQL Server will always complete the insert transactions before querying for the count, resulting in 1.

```
// @TransactionOne
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE T (C INT, D INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES (1, 2);
COMMIT;

// @TransactionTwo
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO T VALUES (3, 4);
COMMIT;
GO

// @Query
SELECT COUNT(*) from T where T.C = 3;
```